# python module in cmd.exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd

There is something I don't understand with a behavior I observed with python modules on windows:

Lets' say I have a module `foo.py` in a certain directory. I open cmd.exe, cd to that directory, then I execute the command `foo` in this shell window. It does not error or anything, it seemingly starts something that exits immediately. The module foo does not itself seem executed by python itself (The module consists of a single `print('foo')` statement, and there is nothing printed). What's going on here ?

Comment: what about some code?

Comment: In the control panel's default-programs file-type association dialog, what's the current association for .py files? Is it "Python File" from "Python Software Foundation" (possibly with a rocket on the Python logo)? If not, double click on the .py entry and select "Python" from the list if it's there. Also, what's the value of the open command for the `Python.File` ProgId? Check `reg query HKCR\Python.File\Shell\open\command`.

Comment: What are the names of all of the `foo.*` files in the directory and `PATH`?

Comment: Is ".py" in your pathext env variable?

Comment: Environment is Windows 10, I see .PY is indeed in the pathext. Python files are associated with pycharm, this is the issue ! Pycharm was already opened when I tested this, so it just reopened that file silently. I'll write the answer myself

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, it's related to both PyCharm file type association and executable extension.

1. .PY is in PATHEXT environement variable. Therefore typing `foo` without the extension will trigger the `foo.py` file
2. If Python files are associated to be opened with pycharm, then typing `foo` in cmd.exe, if it finds a file with that name, will open it in pycharm. Pycharm is apparently smart and doesn't open a new process when another pycharm process already exists, so it opens the `foo.py` file in the current pycharm window.

Thanks to everyone who contributed